# Total number of pleura in the exoskeleton of cockroach

Tags: entomology, anatomy

Basically as far as i know cockroach consists of 10 terga and 9 sterna but what are the total number of pleura present in the cockroach.

Pleura are situated between tergum and sternum of a body segment and help in the articulation of terga and sterna.

What would that be in the case of the 10th abdominal segment in which sternum is absent ? Are pleura present there? If yes then what is their functions at that place?